# Safari can not open this URL error in Admob integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, admob

while clicking on the adds. safari open and shows an alert with message that safari cannot open this URL because URL is invalid. i have used below code to test the adds. m i missing something in this code?

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0,370 ,bannerView_.bounds.size.width, bannerView_.bounds.size.height)];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
// the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
request.testing = YES;
//NSLog(@"Device GUID: %@", uniqueIdentifier);
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       uniqueIdentifier,
                       nil];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Be aware that you can not longer use `[device uniqueIdentifier];` Apple will reject your app.

Comment: do i need to give static value?

Comment: No you need a newer version of the AdMob SDK.

Comment: and i think the the code UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
request.testing = YES;
//NSLog(@"Device GUID: %@", uniqueIdentifier);
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       uniqueIdentifier,
                       nil]; will be removed before uploading the app? right?

Comment: i have downloaded the sdk 5 days ago .. i think its updated.. can you please share the link? and what about the code that i have written for admob?

Comment: You should definitely not be passing the `uniqueIdentifier` into the testDevices to get test ads. Instead, check the logging output when running your app, and you should get a message providing you a hardcoded ID to pass into your app to get test ads on that specific testing device only. This mechanism would get you test ads on every device, which is not what you want.

Comment: Also I don't see you adding the banner to your view hierarchy, but if you're seeing ads on screen, you're probably doing it but just haven't posted it.